# Sending parameter from one function to another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send value from one function to another. But it says undefined when I try to show them in console.
Here I am trying to show `large-image2` id while someone click on `Big()`function. With same image that was in `large-image` id. Which one occur while someone clicked on `lgBox()` function.

Anyone please help

```
function lgBox(url){
    var u = url;
    big(u);
    document.getElementById("large-image").innerHTML="<img src='" + u + "' />";
}
```

Here is my another function. I am sending data here from above function.

```
function big(u) {
    var ul=u;
    alert(ul);
    document.getElementById("large-image2").innerHTML="<img src='" + ul + "' />";}
```

Here big function says undefined while I am trying to show value of ul.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div id="large-image" onclick="big()">
</div>
<div id="large-image2" onclick="lgBoxcross()">
</div>
<div id="thumb-image" >
    <button onclick="lgBox('../images/<?php echo  $singleProductImage['name']; ?>')">
        <img src="../images/<?php echo $singleProductImage['name']; ?>" alt="" class="img">
    </button>
</div>
```

I am not giving my php code here.

Comment: what is the value of `u` when you `console.log` it?

Comment: How is `lgBox` called? check if it gets proper value for `url` variable.

Comment: I think value of url is also undefined.

Comment: while I print u. It shows me correct value. But then my `large-image2` is not called. I mean my `Big()` method's rest work is not done ok

Comment: Is the function name `big()` or `Big()`?

Comment: If you print `u` on `big` function and it shows the correct value. Why not use `u` to assign the src of your `large-image2`?

Comment: sorry. function name is `big()`. and this is ok.

Comment: @Eiddle While I use u. then nothing happen on my click. And says undefined u in my console

Comment: We are missing something here as according to your comments the value is correct.  Please review and perhaps edit to show any differences.  Put the console logs in and add a comment with the values at each point.

Comment: Share the relevant HTML and create a fiddle, please.

Comment: Code has been updated. @Milan Chheda

Comment: There is no parameter on `onclick="big()"`

Comment: I am sending value from `lgBox()` function. then What should be parameter in big(). Sorry it is maybe so easy problem. But as a new I am struggling about this from 2 days.

Comment: My intention is to print `thumb-image` id's image in `large-image` id. And while someone clicked on `large-image` id then that image should show in `large-image2` id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the button, and it works perfectly fine. But if you click on `large-image`, it would show `undefined` as you haven't passed anything in `big()`:

```js
function lgBox(url) {
  document.getElementById("large-image").innerHTML = '<img src="' + url + '"/>';
}


function big(elem) {
  var myimg = elem.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  var mysrc = myimg.src;
  document.getElementById("large-image2").innerHTML = '<img src="' + mysrc + '"/>';
}
```

```html
<div id="large-image" onclick="big(this)">
</div>
<div id="large-image2">
</div>
<div id="thumb-image">
  <button onclick="lgBox('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')">
        button
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: My intention is to print `thumb-image` id's image in `large-image` id. And while someone clicked on `large-image` id then that image should show in `large-image2` id. Can you please help kindly.

Comment: Alright, I have updated my answer based on your above comment.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me boss. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to share a value between functions is to place functions and variables in an event handler. After reading the update, it has become more confusing...I don't see `lgBoxcross()`. Instead of making all of these one off functions, make one function.

In this demo:

- There's only one callback function for all clicks.
- It is bound to a button and when the button is clicked, it will extract the src value of the img (the url of img) that resides within this button.
- It then calls another function `lgBox()` and passes the url through it.
- `lgBox()` takes this url and creates an image in each div.
- Each div has on on event handler when clicked will trigger the main thumbnail button and the same results occur (both divs get the img).

### Demo

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
  var url = this.querySelector('.img').src;
  lgBox.call(this, url);
};

function lgBox(u) {
  var img = "<img src='" + u + "' width='200'style='object-fit:contain'>";
  document.getElementById("large-image1").innerHTML = img;
  document.getElementById("large-image2").innerHTML = img;
}
```

```css
.frame {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="large-image1" class='frame' onclick="btn.click()">
</div>
<div id="large-image2" class='frame' onclick="btn.click()">
</div>
<div id="thumb-image">
  <button id='btn'>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" alt="" width='50' class="img">
    </button>
</div>
```